# Desire2Learn "Org Unit Id" in SOAP and Valence APIs

Tags: desire2learn

In Desire2Learn, does the "Org Unit Id" used when creating grade objects have the same value in both the SOAP and the Valence APIs?  If not, what is the best way to retrieve this value for use with the Valence API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Org Unit IDs are unique identifiers the back-end LMS uses to uniquely identify an Organizational Unit (a department, a course, and so forth). On the same back-end service, you can identify the same org unit with its org unit identifier through both the legacy web services (SOAP) APIs, and the newer Valence REST-ful APIs.